# How can i integrate one SFDC org to another SFDC using Rest Api

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am trying to integrate one Salesforce org to other org by using Oauth setup, I wanted to use  use consumer key and consumer secret key in my `REST` class to connect with the org, after connection part completion, I want to access Get(), Put(), Post(), etc. Including the ability to set Oauth and Authorization headers needed for Salesforce Rest API calls.

Actually I'm new in `REST` implementation so can you please explain me by using code samples.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> One of the ways to Integrate two Salesforce Instances will be using oauth for session management and using REST API
>
> Lets Assume you have SalesforceA as Source ORG and SalesforceB as Destination ORG .Now lets assume flow of data is from SalesforceA to SalesforceB Instance
>
> 1)For oauth 2.0 in Destination org(SalesforceB) create a Connected App .To help you configure the Connected App in Destination below screenshot should assist.Callback Url may not be of any significant as we are using User-Name Password flow model.You will obtain client secret,consumer key in this process and one should store in Source org custom object or custom setting

[image]

> 2)In your source org create a Remote site settings with url as the URL of the Destination Instance
>
> 3)Create a Integration User in the Destination org whose credentials you will use to call API from Salesforce Source ORG
>
> 4)Use the username,password and security token(Also i would prefer setting password never expires here for integration User) and also client secret and consumer key in a custom object or custom setting (Protected) in Source org.

The below code is sample code to get authenticated and how to use access token to further make any API call

```
Settings__c ts=settings;//Here write a sample query or fetch from custom settings the consumer ,client secret and username and password of destination org
 
String clientId = ts.ConsumerKey__c;
String clientSecret = ts.Client_Secret__c;
String username=ts.Username__c;
String password=ts.Password__c+ts.SecurityToken__c;


String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(reqbody);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(ts.URL__c+'/services/oauth2/token');//Note if my domain is set up use the proper domain name else use login.salesforce.com for prod or developer or test.salesforce.com for sandbox instance

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

OAuth2 objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth2)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), OAuth2.class);
RequestWrapper reqst=new RequestWrapper();

if(objAuthenticationInfo.access_token!=null){
   

 
  Http h1 = new Http();
  HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
  req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+objAuthenticationInfo.access_token);
  req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
  
  req1.setBody(jsonstr);//Send JSON body
  req1.setMethod('POST');
  req1.setEndpoint(ts.URL__c+URL);//URL will be your Salesforce REST API end point where you will do POST,PUT,DELETE orGET
  HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
  system.debug('RESPONSE_BODY'+res1 .getbody());
```

> To deserialize the initial response here is wrapper class the above code uses

```
/*To get aouthentication detail Wrapper*/
public class OAuth2{
 public String id{get;set;}
 public String issued_at{get;set;}
 public String instance_url{get;set;}
 public String signature{get;set;}
 public String access_token{get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: How can i implement the same without using users credentials.

Comment: Well you cant implement without user credentials .You need an integration user in any oauth flow that you use sneha

Comment: Thanks Mohith,u said in your previous comment  that we can Integrate two Salesforce Instances in two ways ,whats the second way.

Comment: Why dont you use Salesforce to Salesforce product or use some middle ware like informatica on demand or Talend .Also please upvote the answer as this is how the community works .

Comment: @Mohit How can i connect to external organization by using rest if i have end point url.from that external organization i want to pick data and insert into accounts,contacts,opp,quotes at a time in sfdc. can you  give me sample program.for this requriment.

Comment: What will be your source system to insert data into sfdc?If you use REST you willl have to do oauth to fetch oauth token and then use this token in header to push data into sfdc.You will need wrapper webservices for this requirement .

Comment: @Mohith Kumar ,can u please tell me in this code what is the use of jsonstr and from where it takes reference. and for me this code is not working that code itself creates some problem .

Comment: @sneha JSON will be the data that you are sending to other instance and that code is raw version and it will just give a brief idea of how to proceed

Comment: can any one please tell me in this implementation how can i use get method in OAuth2.0 webserverflow for querying some data from one org.

Comment: @sneha : Were you able to figure out the Salesforce to Salesforce integration using Oauth webserver flow?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Can we use the System Admin as the Integrating user and store his creds in "Custom Settings" along with the Connected App. 
One more question, are we supposed to store connected app details in Custom Settings, can't we pull them directly from the app?

Comment: I am new to REST integration.I followed above steps.After writting apex class how can i call apex class? Do i need to create any button to call webservice.Could you please briefly tell me how shall i proceed to integrate my 2 salesforce orgs.

Comment: I would update the answer to make sure that the strings are URL encoded.  I kept getting a bad request response from the server because I did not have my  pw encoded. -  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(password, 'UTF-8')

Answer (score 2):

A method for doing this without storing credentials is described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/04/integrating-multi-orgs-using-oauth.html

In brief:
 IN HUB ORG
 1. Generate a X509 Certificate file and Private Key
 2. Create a Connected App in the Salesforce Hub Org
 3. Click the Use digital signatures checkbox, click the Choose File button and select the Certificate file that was created above (e.g. mycert.cer)
 4. Set OAuth policies
 5. For the Require Users to Log in radio button, select Refresh Token is valid until revoked.
 6. Add Approved Profile to the Connected App
 IN SPOKE ORG:
 7. Update Remote Site Settings
 8. Create Apex Code ([sample here](https://github.com/jejhgithub/saml-bearer-assertion-apex-example))

Comment: Please add a rough gist of the linked content here if it answers the question. Links may go dead over time, rendering link-only answers completely useless.