# Integrate two Salesforce developer orgs

Tags: integration

How do we integrate two salesforce orgs. I have two developer orgs and I am attempting to establish data transfer between them. I am creating a record of a Account in org A, is it possible to obtain that record in org B. Kindly tell me how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into Salesforce to Salesforce? It should be available for your developer orgs.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox that looks to be a great solution. Out of curiosity, if we were to write custom code for this purpose. I will create a web service method in the information providing org, but could you tell me as to how to invoke it from the first org to get the information. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are ways to integrate SFDC dev org to dev org

**SALESFORCE TO SALESFORCE**

Probably the easiest one and offered out of box .

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce

**REST API**

To connect two salesforce instance you will create Connected App in the transmitter or publisher org.And you will consume the standard REST API in the subscriber org or reciever org .

Take a look at one of my previous answers to dig deeper

[How can i integrate one SFDC org to another SFDC using Rest Api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25021/how-can-i-integrate-one-sfdc-org-to-another-sfdc-using-rest-api)

**Named Credentials**

Using named credentials you can do in few lines .Check below blog

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/

**External Objects**

External objects in production come at cost but in developer orgs they are free .With new release you can write and read from external objects .

Check the below article to dig deeper

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm

You will create an external data source as salesforce and in another instance consume the same

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=xorg_add_external_data_source.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @Mohith - that's a really interesting point about leveraging External Objects in a Developer org! Do you have any more information on this? Thanks!