# Integrate one SFDC org to another SFDC using Rest Api

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration

I want to implement integrating 2 salesforce orgs.I followed below Q&A from stackexchange.I have written apex class also.I am not sure how to call this rest apex class.Do i need to add any custom button for this.

[How can i integrate one SFDC org to another SFDC using Rest Api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25021/how-can-i-integrate-one-sfdc-org-to-another-sfdc-using-rest-api][1])

Comment: what is your requirement ? Yes you can call from custom button

Comment: how often should the integration occur? on a scheduled basis? as each record in Org 1 changes values? Can your Apex REST class handle bulk updates or only single SObjects?

Answer (score 1):

Few months back, I've written in detail(step by step) to connect 2 salesforce orgs using Rest API

[https://cloudvista.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/connecting-one-salesforce-org-to-another-via-rest-api/](http://Connect%202%20salesforce%20orgs)

Please go through it and revert in case of any questions.

Comment: @curious_techy-Above link is not going through.It gives error.

Comment: access directly like this :     https://cloudvista.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/connecting-one-salesforce-org-to-another-via-rest-api/

Answer (score -1):

You can call that class through trigger with specific values.

If you need more clarity on this tell me what purpose you implemented the class and post this class here.

Thanks,

Sandy

Comment: Sandy -- welcome to SFSE; etiquette here is not ask OP to contact you directly via email as that doesn't add value to the community and has the appearance of soliciting consulting work.