# Session expired or invalid

Tags: rest-api, integration, error, salesforce2salesforce, namedcredentials

I am trying to build Salesforce to Salesforce integration using Named Credentials.

Followed steps from below blog.

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/

- Created Connected App in destination org
- Created Authorization Provider in source org
- Defined Named Credential in source org.

  ```
  HttpRequest feedRequest = new HttpRequest();

  feedRequest.setEndpoint('callout:Dev3Org/services/data/v32.0');

  feedRequest.setMethod('GET');

  Http http = new Http();

  HTTPResponse feedResponse = http.send(feedRequest);
  ```

When I ran above code in Source Org (anonymous window) then am getting below error

> Session expired or invalid

Comment: [do Named Credentials periodically refresh the access token, or is that on us?](https://twitter.com/bigassforce/status/677264560047325184)

Comment: check whether this helps you out:
[Integration](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25021/how-can-i-integrate-one-sfdc-org-to-another-sfdc-using-rest-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when I checked Generate Authorization Header check box on Named Credential then error went off.

[image]

Comment: hey, where is the above option in salesforce dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Named credentials works fine.  It looks like request is reaching the host and you are getting the response as session expired. In Named Credentials you can set  basic authentication or  oauth  please check which one of them are being used.

Comment: I have specified OAuth 2.0 in Named Credentials

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Finally... I am able to get the response from other org...

Make sure that while creating named credentials.. you should give URI as "https://xxxxxxxxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com"

I gave "xxxxxxxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com" >>> Throwed the error...

so correct URI is "https://xxxxxxxxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com".